# wget and htaccess: username only

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wget

I googled how to download images using terminal in ubuntu with wget. I found what I needed, but on the server, protected with .htaccess, there's no password. with

`wget admin@http://server.com/filename.jpg`

it returns: No route to hosts. When I set a password and type

`wget admin:password@http://server.com/filename.jpg`

everything's fine. However I am not allowed to use a password on the server. How to fix it, finding route?

Answer (score 29):

Much easier:

```
wget --user="username" --password="password" http://xxxx.yy/filename.xxx
```

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
wget --user=admin http://server.com/filename.jpg
```

instead.

Alternatively,

```
wget http://admin:@server.com/filename.jpg
```

may work instead.

Your syntax is actually wrong, as its:

```
wget http://user:pass@host/file
```

your username is outside the url, and was being treated as a hostname.

Comment: I read somewhere that this is the right format for wget. In HTML when I enter <img src=http://user@server.com/filename.jpg /> everything is fine, it displays. But I need to download it and wget http://user@server.com/filename.jpg doesn't work.

Comment: Then try the `wget --user=...` version.

Comment: DONE. wget --user=admin --password='' http://server.com/filename.jpg Pay attention to --password. It equals just a pair of quotes.